# 2017 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Game Development's [third moderator election](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/election/3) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 2 new moderators are:

[image: DMGregory] [image: Alexandre Vaillancourt]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/election/3), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5789644658573312/0).

Comment: Awesome! Congrats to the winners. :)

Comment: Thank you! I'm looking forward to helping maintain and grow our community together. :)

Comment: Thanks @Almo! I'm looking forward to help the community too!